# How do I make python try the next URL in my file if the current one returns a 404?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm having a problem figuring out what code I need to create to make to make python try the next url in my csv file each url is on a line like this:

---

http://www.indexedamerica.com/states/PR/Adjuntas/Restaurants-Adjuntas-00601.html
http://www.indexedamerica.com/states/PR/Aguada/Restaurants-Aguada-00602.html
http://www.indexedamerica.com/states/PR/Aguadilla/Restaurants-Aguadilla-00603.html
http://www.indexedamerica.com/states/PR/Aguadilla/Restaurants-Aguadilla-00604.html
http://www.indexedamerica.com/states/PR/Aguadilla/Restaurants-Aguadilla-00605.html
http://www.indexedamerica.com/states/PR/Maricao/Restaurants-Maricao-00606.html
http://www.indexedamerica.com/states/MI/Kent/Restaurants-Grand-Rapids-49503.html

---

```
#open csv file
#read csv file line by line
#Pass each line to beautiful soup to try
#If URL raises a 404 error continue to next line
#extract tables from url

from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv

mech = Browser()
indexed = open('C://python27/longlist.csv')
reader = csv.reader(indexed)
html = mech.open(reader)

for line in html:
    try:
        mechanize.open(html)
        table = soup.find("table", border=3)
else:
#!!!! try next url from file. How do I do this?

for row in table.findAll('tr')[2:]:
    col = row.findAll('td')
    BusinessName = col[0].string
    Phone = col[1].string
    Address = col[2].string
    City = col[3].string
    State = col[4].string
    Zip = col[5].string
    Restaurantinfo = (BusinessName, Phone, Address, City, State)
print "|".join(Restaurantinfo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for line in html:
    try:
        mechanize.open(html)
        table = soup.find("table", border=3)
    except Exception:
        continue
```

Alternatively, you could check the status code of the page, and skip if you receive a 404 (in a for loop):

```
if urllib.urlopen(url).getcode() == '404':
    continue
```

`continue` in a loop, stops execution of further code and continues to the next entry in the loop.

Comment: I'm literally a decade late on commenting here. 
This did indeed solve my issue.
Thanks for helping me get better when I was just starting. 
Hope you're well.

Answer (score 1):

Add all the urls you want to search through to a list. Then loop through the list, opening each url in sequence. If a given url returns any kind of error then you can choose to use continue to ignore that url-file and move on to the next one.

Comment: Just use a list, and iterate through the list.